# Mono SVN Post-Commit Hook not exiting when run under Apache

Tags: c#, apache, svn, mono, exit

We have an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS SVN server replacing our original Windows 2003 server. Both are running SVN via Apache. Part of the deal is that our existing .Net commit hooks are ported over - these handle things such as updating our project tracker and firing build jobs. For the most part I have succeeded - most things run natively under Mono. I have installed `mono-complete` on the server.

When run under a normal user on the server, and with `sudo -u www-data`, the hook runs and exits cleanly and correctly. I have also tried invoking Mono with `env -` to give an empty environment, but the process still completes as expected.

The problem comes when the hook fires. Mono is invoked and the program proceeds as normal. However, it does not exit. I have put extensive logging in the program and it returns to Main(), from where it should be returning an exit code on completion. This does not happen; instead, it hangs infinitely. Performing an `strace` on the process returns `futex(0x982440, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL` so it sounds like the process is waiting for something. This behaviour occurs in both .Net 3.5 and .Net 4.0.

The obvious problem here is that control does not return to svn until the hook exits, so the client continues to wait on commit.

The one thing I have noticed is that there frequently (but not always) appear to be two instances running when viewed in `htop`, one running under Apache, and a second running directly under init. It's as if Mono has incompletely forked the process. They both have to be killed with SIGKILL; they do not respond to SIGTERM, and killing one does not affect the other.

I am at my wit's end here. There are no security limits set on processes. Replacing Main() returning int with void and explicitly calling Environment.Exit() does not work either. It seems control simply will not return from the hook to the system.

Edit: I have just tried on a Debian 7 server set up in much the same way and encounter exactly the same problem. Both have `mono-complete` installed. On Ubuntu, it is v3.2.8. On Debian, it is v2.10.8.1. I really am completely stuck now.

Edit 2: on the advice of a friend, I set up the PCH as a cron job to see if the lack of TTY is causing the issue. It works as expected under cron and exits cleanly. No hanging processes. I am at a total loss to explain this.

Edit 3: on the advie of another friend, I tried explicitly creating a shell to run the PCH:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -ne 3 ]; then echo "Expected exactly three arguments (given $#, values $*). Use: $0 repository revision transaction" 1>&2; exit 1; fi

logfile="/var/svn/postcommithook/postcommithook.log";
repo=$1;
revision=$2;

echo "$(date) Starting post-commit for $repo at $revision" >> $logfile;

author=$(svnlook author $repo -r $revision);

echo "$(date) Running post-commit hooks" >> $logfile;
/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/mono /var/svn/postcommithook/PostCommitHook.exe $repo $revision $author verbose < /dev/null >> $logfile 2>&1"

if [ $? != 0 ]; then echo "$(date) Post-Commit failed with error code $? - commit has succeeded" >> $logfile; exit $?; fi

echo "$(date) Complete" >> $logfile;
```

No dice. Still hangs. Why won't this process exit?